# SSRS Sub reports doesn't show it's own footer

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0, reportbuilder

I have an SSRS report that has two sub reports in it, each one has full structure Header, Body and footer.

Now My problem is when I render main report my sub reports doesn't show **Footer**

There is a way to force footer be printed at each sub ?

Comment: This is by design. (Sub)Report headers and footers are ommited when report is embedded in another report

Comment: One idea is to copy the footer from the sub to the calling report. Subs never show headers or footers, in some cases you may want to remove them entirely if they are never meant to be run on their own.

Comment: Should not Microsoft do re-design and do an enhancement? I have same kind of problem as well. Using SSRS 2017.